# Data Matrices Definiteness In Semidefinite Programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

I'm little bit confused about the data matrices associated with an SDP program. Consider the following SDP program:

[image]

I know that the Matrix $X$ must be positive semidefinite i.e. $X \succeq 0$ as the last constraint implies. My question is about the data matrices $C$ and $A_i \forall i \in \{1, \cdots, m\}$. Do they have to be positive semidefinite ? In other words, can we have a matrix $C$ for example  that is either negative definite or indefinite ?

Comment: Yes, positive semidefiniteness is only enforced on $X$, not $C$

Comment: @user1936752 thank you for your answer. Do they have to be symmetrical (matrices $C$ and $A$)?

Comment: Due to the symmetry of $X$ one can always make $C$ and $A$ symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not need $C$ to be positive semidefinite.  It is an extension of linear programming.

$C\cdot X=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}X_{ij}$

Note that due to $X$ is symmetric we have $$C_{ij}X_{ij}+C_{ji}X_{ji}=(C_{ij}+C_{ji})X_{ij},$$

we can obtain the same expression using symmetric matrix by using $\frac12(C+C^T)$ instead. Hence, usually for simplicity, we just states that we want $C$ and $A_i$ to be symmetric.